# Decode String to date

Tags: sql, plsql

I need help to decode a String. I think i need a PL/SQL script to decode the String but my knowledge in PL / SQL are not particularly.

I have a Table which contains 7 Column’s

- First Colum includes the Objectnumber
- Second column Includes a Year
- Third Column Includes a number which belongs to  the next fields
- Fourth column includes a Text which describes the last 3 Fields
- And column 5 to 7 Includes the string which should be decoded.
- The Columns 5 to 7 (T1,T2, T3) should be decoded to a date. (each number is a day where the object moves, an “=” (equal) or a “0” (zero) means the object does not move on this day)
- The Number describes also a day.

Example

```
1 = Monday
2 = Tuesday
3 = Wednesday
4 = Thursday
5 = Friday
6 = Saturday
7 = Sunday
8 = Holiday (25.12 =Christmas day)
```

- The T1 Field has a length from 23, that’s means the date starts from 09.12.2012 and ends on 31.12.2012
- The T2 Field has a length from 181, that’s means the date starts from 01.01.2013 and ends on 30.06.2013
- The T3 Field has a length from 167, that’s means the date starts from 01.07.2013 and ends on 14.12.2013

The T1 Field ends always on 31.12.XXYY
and The Filed T2 and T3 Starts always on the same Day T2 starts on 01.01.XXYY and T3 starts on 01.07.2013

in the first row I have object 1244 with Num 8 and text filed “tgl” and behind the T1-T3 Field’s
and about this I can see that’s object 1244 moves each day beginning from 09.12.2012 until 14.12.2013
object 120 with num 6 and 27 moves only on working days and Saturdays
and object 169 have num 13 and the T1 to T3 Fields have only 7 or 8 which means this object moves only on Sunday and Holiday

Table example:

```
object Year    Num   text    T1                         T2                                                                                                                                                                                       T3
1244   2013    8     tgl     71234567123456718845671    8345671234567123456712345671234567123456712345671234567123456712345671234567123456712345678234567123456712345671234567128456712385671234567823456712385671234567123456712345671234567    12345671234567123456712345671234567123456712385671234567123456712345671234567123456712345671234567123456712345671234587123486712345671234567123456712345671234567123456
120    2013    6     Sa      ======6======6======6==    ====6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6=    =====6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======6======8======6======6======6======6======6======6======6
120    2013    27    X(Sa)   =12345==12345==1==45==1    =345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345===2345==12345==12345==12345==12=45==123=5==12345===2345==123=5==12345==12345==12345==12345==    12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==123=5==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==1234===12345==12345==12345==12345==12345==12345=
169    2013    13    +       7======7======7=88===7=    8====7======7======7======7======7======7======7======7======7======7======7======7======78=====7======7======7======7==8===7===8==7======78=====7===8==7======7======7======7======7    ======7======7======7======7======7======7===8==7======7======7======7======7======7======7======7======7======7=====87====8=7======7======7======7======7======7======
```

And what I need is:
I need all days from an Object when it moves (should be usable for SQL Statements)
So Rows object, Year, num, Text, decoded day

```
Example:
Object  Year    Num     text        Day
1244        2013    8       tgl     09.12.2012
1244        2013    8       tgl     10.12.2012
1244        2013    8       tgl     11.12.2012
...    ....
```

Comment: I'm curious to know what kind of system generates this kind of data.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like T1-T3 act like a calendar. I can't fathom why the data is divided into three columns. I will assume that `T1||T2||T3` is a calendar where each letter is a day in the year that starts with `01-01-YEAR`, modify with your own set of business rules.

It doesn't look like the numbers in the calendar matter for your query and so your problem appears as a simple pivot, which you can solve with different methods, such as ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11928)):

```
SQL> SELECT ID, YEAR, num, text, substr(t1 || t2 || t3, lvl, 1) subst,
  2         to_date(YEAR||'-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + lvl - 1 dt
  3    FROM DATA
  4   CROSS JOIN (SELECT ROWNUM lvl
  5                 FROM dual
  6              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX(length(t1 || t2 || t3))
  7                                     FROM DATA))
  8   WHERE substr(t1 || t2 || t3, lvl, 1) != '='
  9  ORDER BY 1 DESC, lvl;

        ID       YEAR        NUM TEXT            SUBST  DT
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ------ -----------
      1244       2013          8 tgl             7      01/01/2013
      1244       2013          8 tgl             1      02/01/2013
      1244       2013          8 tgl             2      03/01/2013
      1244       2013          8 tgl             3      04/01/2013
      1244       2013          8 tgl             4      05/01/2013
      1244       2013          8 tgl             5      06/01/2013
```

Comment: Hi,many thanks for the help!! the Problem is, the table will be filled from a very old acces db :-(. and i have to check something.

Many thanks!